# Microsoft WPF Ribbon - 64-bit support?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, ribbon

In the document "Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October 2010 Update Release Notes" ([WPFRibbonOctober2010-ReleaseNotes.rtf](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877)) , it states the following:

> **System Requirements for Installing Microsoft Ribbon for WPF**
>
> ...
>
> - Supported Architectures:
>
>   - x86
>   - x64 (WPF Ribbon is only provided in x86, however, *the components    will install and function properly on x64 operating systems*)

Regarding the significance of the final bullet - what specifically is provided only in x86? For a .NET library this seems a little odd, maybe there are some unmanaged DLLs also?

This could be relevant in a deployment scenario and I just find the wording somewhat vague.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but reading the x64 bullet point seems like a rather akward attempt at trying to convey that the WPF Ribbon is only usable in 32-bit applications, but that you shouldn't worry, because x64 Windows can run 32-bit applications too. That's how i would read that; but then again i am not really an authorative voice you should listen to. If in doubt, try using the WPF ribbon with a little test WPF appliaction that specifically targets x64 and see whether it works.

Comment: Come to think of it, the term "components" might perhaps refer to the ribbon being provided by some 32-bit COM component(s) that the WPF ribbon code interfaces with. If that is the case, the WPF ribbon might be usable in a x64 application, with the 32-bit COM component(s)
 running as an "out-of-process COM server".